# What implementations of Tor are there?

Tags: implementations

I have seen implementations such as the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and a [TorChat](https://github.com/prof7bit/TorChat/downloads), based on the Tor network. I was wondering if there were any more of them out there?

Comment: Do you mean implementations of the Tor protocol? Or applications that use Tor? (TorChat uses the Tor Projects Tor client under the hood, so uses Tor rather than implementing it, if you see what I mean)

Comment: [Torpy](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy) -- pure python tor protocol implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, there is [main tor implementation](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git), the one in C.

There is also a Java version of Tor in development, called [JTor](https://github.com/brl/JTor), however it has not be 'released' yet.

Finally, there is an implementation of Tor written in python using the Scapy library called 
[TorPylle](https://github.com/cea-sec/TorPylle), but it is an experimental implementation more to explain the protocol and should not be used.

There also exist number of projects that use tor as backend, but do not itself implement it (they might bundle tor, but do not maintain their own source code). There is a [list](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en) of projects that The Tor Project maintains.

Answer (score 1):

> [JonDo](https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/) has [Tor support, but it is experimental.](https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/help/services_tor.html)

Answer (score 0):

check out this (my own project): https://github.com/briand-hub/toresp32
client/proxy for Linux and ESP32 platform. Very well commented code for educational purposes, written in modern C++!
Hope helps you, bye!