# How many Tor-like networks are around?

Tags: onion-routing

I'm about an idea, **onion routing**.

Are there a secret or governments or a half-secret projects with similar technology?

For example, [DARPA-BAA-10-69](https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=form&id=72b1394a8dfb088886588067f70a27b8&tab=core&_cview=1) is a project called "SAFER" (May 20, 2010).

> The goal of the Safer Warfighter Communications (SAFER) program is to
>   develop technology that will enable safe, resilient communications
>   over the Internet, particularly in situations in which a third-party
>   is attempting to discover the identity or location of the end users,
>   or block the communication.

Is it a fork of earlier(Navy's) version of Tor?

Is there any fork of Tor? For example Navy's version. Or Navy use a [torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org)?

Comment: If you mean implementation of the [Tor Protocol Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/tor-spec.txt) then there is already a question with replies: [What implementations of Tor are there?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/7/114) If you mean implementation of systems based on similar principles as Tor then this is a valid new question. Please clarify.

Comment: I mean system based on the same principles as Tor, onion routing.

Comment: I do not know why did you reject my edit. Your question as it is now (mainly its title) is too confusing. Could you please fix it yourself?

Comment: I make little change, see.

Answer (score 2):

To answer you questions in order:

> "Are there a secret or governments or a half-secret projects with similar technology?"

Well, if they're cloaked in secrecy it's unlikely anyone on StackExchange could tell you much about them. :)  Moreover, law enforcement and the military [*do* in fact use Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/torusers.html.en#military).

> "Is it [DARPA-BAA-10-69] a fork of earlier(Navy's) version of Tor?"

Hard to say, but there have been other programs that used onion routing.  [BitBlinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitblinder) was an example, and perhaps the only example.

You may enjoy researching [garlic routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic_routing), on which [I2P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P) and [Perfect Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Dark_(P2P)) are based.