# Are there any Javascript implementations of Tor client?

Tags: javascript, implementations

Are there any available Javascript implementations of Tor client?

Links:

- [What implementations of Tor are there?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-implementations-of-tor-are-there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [node-Tor](https://github.com/Ayms/node-Tor), but I am not sure what their status is.

Answer (score 0):

https://subgraph.com/orchid/index.en.html

> Orchid is a Tor client implementation and library written in pure
>   Java. It was written from the Tor specification documents, which are
>   available here. Orchid runs on Java 5+ and the Android devices.
>
> In a basic use case, running Orchid will open a SOCKS5 listener which
>   can be used as a standalone client where Tor would otherwise be used.
>
> Orchid can also be used as a library by any application running on the
>   JVM. This is what Orchid was really designed for and this is the
>   recommended way to use it. Orchid can be used as a library in any Java
>   application, or any application written in a language that compiles
>   bytecode that will run on the Java virtual machine, e.g., JRuby,
>   Clojure, Scala..

Comment: Java != JavaScript, not even close

Comment: True, my bad. I did not catch that it was javascript and not java when I read it the first time. Thanks for pointing it out.